# Extract all Contact Key and Device ID from Mobile Push

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

As the title suggests, I'm trying to extract the Contact Key and Device ID of all my Push contacts. I'm aware of the `_PushAddress` data view but this contains the Contact ID and not the Contact Key.

Is there anyway to extract this? Maybe through Salesforce directly?

I'm aware I could potentially join the _Subscribers data view, but this will only reveal contacts that have received email comms, no one thats exclusively received push notifications only.

Answer (score 2):

Try going into Mobile Push and creating a filtered list based on All Contacts where Device ID is not null - this should return a list of all your MobilePush Subscriber that you can download to get all the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not. You can reach out to Salesforce Services and have them build a Custom Data View for you. Or you can use this work around described in the accepted answer. [Can I query to all contacts in contact builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285257/can-i-query-to-all-contacts-in-contact-builder/285259#285259)

Not sure if it is something you want to automate. Otherwise you could just export the list once you have created it.